# Align TextView leftmost after adding a newline

Tags: android, xml, textview, alignment

I'm using SQLite to show buy log from database in my project. I'm appending every row data in StringBuffer and then adding a newline after that. But what I want is that each newline starts from the same position. Like in the picture where the **black bar** is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZGDG.png)

I can't find a way to do this. any help will be appreciated.

Here is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buyTv"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my java code for this:

```
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            buffer.append("BuyID: " + cursor.getString(0) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Time: " + cursor.getString(1) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Product Name: " + cursor.getString(2) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Price: " + cursor.getString(3) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Quantity: " + cursor.getString(4) + "\n");
            buffer.append("Total Cost: " + cursor.getString(5) + "\n\n");
        }

        String temp = buffer.toString();

        tv.setText(temp);
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the gravity of your textview to `start` or `left` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/buyTv"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
```

Comment: if I use left gravity the TextView align from very left position but I want them in center with same starting position!

Comment: Thanks! that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the property of the TextView

```
android:gravity="center"
```

or modify it into

```
android:gravity="left"
```

in your XML file. This property makes your text align in center.

Comment: If I use left gravity the TextView align from very left position but I want them in center with same starting position!

Comment: @Rafat You can continue to modify the `android:layout_width` property of your TextView as `WRAP_CONTENT` .